# Unexpected behavior with while loop conditions and custom classes

Tags: python

I'm trying to write the code to find the center of a linked list ([leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/middle-of-the-linked-list/)), but I can't understand why a solution code works.

This is the initial code to set up the custom class and test data. There are 4 nodes now.

```
# Given a non-empty, singly linked list with head node head, return a middle node of linked list.
# If there are two middle nodes, return the second middle node.

class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

x1 = ListNode(1)
x2 = ListNode(2)
x1.next = x2
x3 = ListNode(3)
x2.next = x3
x4 = ListNode(4)
x3.next = x4
```

I'll need to find the center of the linked list, so the solution should retrieve node number three.

**Solution code #1** solves the problem.

```
# This works
slow = fast = x1

while fast and fast.next:
  slow = slow.next
  fast = fast.next.next
print(slow.val)
```

**Solution code #2** does not solve the problem.

```
# This doesn't work
slow = fast = x1

while fast.next:
  slow = slow.next
  fast = fast.next.next
print(slow.val)
```

**Question 1:** The only difference is the condition in the while loop. Why does removing `fast and` in the condition break the code (as seen in solution #2)?

**Question 2:** I also noticed that for solution #1, `while fast and fast.next:` does not evaluate to `True`, but yet the while loop still runs. Should't the while loop runs only when the condition is True?

```
while fast and fast.next:
  print(fast == True)
  print(fast.next == True)
  slow = slow.next
  fast = fast.next.next
print(slow.val)
```

Comment: it breaks the code because `fast` can have a value of `None`, so you're basically calling `None.next`, which raises an exception, because `None` does not have a property called `next`. Which is why the `if fast` condition is important there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

As a good practice - You will always prefer to check if class is `not None` before trying to access inner members - in the 2'nd solution when the line `fast.next` runs - you never checked if `fast` exist at first place. therefore, when `fast` is actually None, at last iteration, the program fails.

**question 2**

the statement: `while fast and fast.next:` implicitly actually say `while fast is not None and fast.next is not None:` explicitly.

fetched only when is `True` when printing it:

```
while fast is not None and fast.next is not None:
    print(fast is not None and fast.next is not None)
    slow = slow.next
    fast = fast.next.next
print(slow.val)
```

output:

```
True
True
3
```

as you can see, evaluates only when `True` - there are no `False` prints